# multiprocessing, process dies out or doesn't initialise

Tags: python, tweepy, python-multiprocessing

I have a class with function `stream` which takes input as array words and executes a function (streaming tweepy) which I have imported from another python file as a different process.

When I run the code and check status of process using `is_alive()` it returns `False`. That clearly shows that process is not running. When I call the function directly without using `Process` it runs as expected.

```
def stream(self,track=[]):
    self.data.append(track)
    print len(self.data)
    self.streamobj = Process(target = startstream, args=(self.data,))
    #startstream(self.data)
    self.streamobj.start()
```

here is the function I am importing and it takes array as input which contains all api keys and keywords to filter

```
def startstream(data):
    print data
    auth = OAuthHandler(data[0], data[1])
    auth.set_access_token(data[2], data[3])
    twitterStream = Stream(auth,Listener())
    twitterStream.filter(track=data[4])
```

I want to use multiprocessing to execute this but failing to do so

**Error Code**

`Process(Process-1, stopped[1])`

this means that process had an error but cannot understand what the error is

Comment: Can you post codes to show how you create an instance of the `stream` class?